# Does AzureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync cache tokens across instances (of the provider)?

Tags: c#, azure

The documentation states:

> The `AzureServiceTokenProvider` class caches the token in memory and retrieves it from Azure AD just before expiration. So, you no longer have to check the expiration before calling the `GetAccessTokenAsync` method. Just call the method when you want to use the token.

Is this true even if I use a new instance of `AzureServiceTokenProvider` each time, or do I need to use the same instance?

```cs
var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
_accessToken = await tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(_msiOptions.AppId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The cache is static so it is shared across instances.

The token provider uses this class as the cache: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/ddda7cb74b979f03bb03e240c06c924914ee8bdd/src/SdkCommon/AppAuthentication/Azure.Services.AppAuthentication/Cache/AccessTokenCache.cs.

As you can see, it has a static ConcurrentDictionary.

Comment: It is actually using [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/mgmtcommon/AppAuthentication/Azure.Services.AppAuthentication/Cache/AppAuthResultCache.cs) class, even when the answer was written.